# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlException though all jar files added

Tags: java, excel

I am trying to access an excel sheet but it keeps on giving me this error on this line:

```
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
```

I have pretty much added all the jar files that are out there but it is still not working. 
[image]

[image]

Comment: You have added the xmlbeans as a zip file. Extract xmlbeans-2.30.jar.zip and add the jar file.

Answer (score 1):

XmlBeans should be added as a jar file. 
Extract xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar.zip and add the jar file.